# "super" e variáveis privadas

Tags: java, classes, herança, private, super

No caso abaixo, faz sentido chamar `super()` na classe `B_Class` haja visto que a variável `a` de `A_Class` é privada? Seria mais viável não utilizar o construtor da classe mãe?

Compilar esse código acusa erro no método `return_number` da `B_Class` dizendo que `a` é privada na classe mãe.

```
public class A_Class {
    private int a;

    A_Class(int num){
        this.a = a;
    }
}

public class B_Class extends A_Class {
    B_Class(int num){
        super(num);
    }

    public int return_number(){
        return this.a;
    }
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

O código não faz muito sentido, começando por `this.a = a` está fazendo nada útil, está atribuindo uma variável por ela mesma. Pra fazer isso não precisa de construtor.

Se não tem o construtor ali, então não tem porque ter outro construtor na classe estendida, a não ser por um motivo específico.

Essa é uma questão, talvez ajude ler [Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101).

O erro apresentado é diferente disso tudo e não há relação entre eles.

Está tentando acessar um campo que não existe na classe derivada e por isso não pode ser acessada. Se deseja que esse campo possa ser acessado na classe derivada então o campo na base deve ser no mínimo `protected`.

Um campo declarado como privado só é acessível na classe onde foi declarado, é detalhe de implementação dele, a classe derivada não tem acesso a ele. Claro que o objeto terá esse campo para as operações da classe base, mas não para as operações da classe derivada. A não ser de forma indireta, este código parece fazer mais sentido, ainda que mantenha o artificialismo e só dê para demonstrar o mecanismo e não OOP:

```
class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        var b = new B(5);
        System.out.println(b.getA());
    }
}
class A {
    private int a;

    A(int num) {
        a = num;
    }
    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    B(int num) {
        super(num);
    }
    @Override
    public int getA() {
        return super.getA();
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/VpQGhQ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/opadtcyr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/OOP/AccessBase.java).

Não trate isso como um bom modelo. Quando está programando orientado a objeto é preciso saber o que é o problema e o que é necessário. Artificialmente esses projetos sempre saem errado, porque mudando um pequeno detalhe todo o código pode não ser válido mais.